# Combine hibernate.xml and spring-dispatcher.xml

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am new in the concept of spring and hibernate. I learnt hibernate and spring both separate. Now i have made project which uses both spring and hibernate. I have kept them separate and my project is working fine. But requirement is to merge both configuration. i am trying to do this but it seems very difficult because if i change little whole project is not working. 
my hibernate.cfg.xml is kept inside src folder and it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">  
    <hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory>

            <!-- Database connection settings -->
            <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
            <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb</property>
            <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
            <property name="connection.password">root</property>

            <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
            <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
            <!-- SQL dialect -->
            <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
            <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
            <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
            <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
            <property name="show_sql">true</property>
            <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
            <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
            <mapping class="com.csc.StudentAdmission.Student" />
        </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

my spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml is kept inside WEB-INF folder, it is

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.csc.StudentAdmission" />
        <mvc:annotation-driven/>
        <!--<bean id="HandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />-->   
        <!-- <bean name="/welcome.html" class ="csc.csc.helloController.HelloController" /> -->

    <bean id="viewResolver" class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name ="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

and finaly my web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>SpringMVC</display-name>
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

please help me in this concept.

Comment: "But requirement is to merge both configuration" - Merge how?

Comment: keep the hibernate connection into spring-dispatcher.servlet.xml

Comment: Can someone help please. i got stuck in this and i am not getting any solution.

Comment: What is the reason to do so? It seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

you can find several answers for integrating Spring with Hibernate. Here are some references:

From Spring official document:

[15.3 Hibernate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html)

From JournalDev site:

[Spring Bean Configuration File for Hibernate 3 Integration](http://www.journaldev.com/3524/spring-hibernate-integration-example-tutorial-spring-4-hibernate-3-and-hibernate-4)

Sample taken from this site shows how to map using annotated entites and hbm mapping files.

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TestDB" />
        <property name="username" value="pankaj" />
        <property name="password" value="pankaj123" />
    </bean>

<!-- Hibernate 3 XML SessionFactory Bean definition-->
<!--     <bean id="hibernate3SessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>person.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean> -->

<!-- Hibernate 3 Annotation SessionFactory Bean definition-->
    <bean id="hibernate3AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.journaldev.model.Person</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="personDAO" class="com.journaldev.dao.PersonDAOImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate3AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```